# Understanding 'Category' scale in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
s = pd.Series(['Low', 'Low', 'High', 'Medium', 'Low', 'High', 'Low'])

s.astype('category', categories=['Low', 'Medium', 'High'], ordered=True)
print(s>'Low')
```

Output:

```
0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
4    False
5    False
6    False
dtype: bool
```

Doubt: As i have described in category that LowLow' it should return True for both Medium as well as High. But it is returning True for Medium only, why? what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my version of `pandas` the parameter `categories` is not valid for `.astype()`. To do what you want you need an instance of `CategoricalDtype`:

```py
from pandas.api.types import CategoricalDtype

s = pd.Series(['Low', 'Low', 'High', 'Medium', 'Low', 'High', 'Low'])
cat_type = CategoricalDtype(categories=['Low', 'Medium', 'High'], ordered=True)
s = s.astype(cat_type)
print(s>'Low')
```

```
0    False
1    False
2     True
3     True
4    False
5     True
6    False
dtype: bool
```

See more in the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/categorical.html).

A bit cleaner way to do this, i.e. without the explicit import, is using [`pd.Categorical()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Categorical.html):

```py
raw_cat = pd.Categorical(
    ['Low', 'Low', 'High', 'Medium', 'Low', 'High', 'Low'],
    categories=['Low', 'Medium', 'High'],
    ordered=True
)

s = pd.Series(raw_cat)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here  , s is a series of strings , when you do this : (s>'Low')

Here strings are getting compared , when you consider ASCII values ( H-72, L-76, M-77).

Only Medium(M-77) is greater than Low(L-76), but High(H-72) is lesser than Low(L-76).

I Hope you got my point.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the sum of the ASCII value of 'low' is smaller than others but the hash value is not.

According to Ascii sum-

```
["Low","Medium","high"]

  306    609     384
```

hash values-

```
low
L= sum(1 0 0 1 1 0 0) =3
o= sum(1 1 0 1 1 1 1) =6
w= sum(1 1 1 0 1 1 1) =6
                  sum =21
High
H=sum(1 0 0 1 0 0 0) =2
i=sum(1 1 0 1 0 0 1) =4
g=sum(1 1 0 0 1 1 1) =5
h=sum(1 1 0 1 0 0 0) =3
                 sum =14
Medium
M=sum(1 0 0 1 1 0 1) =4
i=sum(1 1 0 0 1 0 1) =4
d=sum(1 1 0 0 1 0 0) =3
i=sum(1 1 0 1 0 0 1) =4
u=sum(1 1 1 0 1 0 1) =5
m=sum(1 1 0 1 1 0 1) =5
                 sum =25
```

As you can see High is the smallest word, you can swap low and high or use numbers to denote the word.
I would recommend using numbers